# How can I improve the power usage of my home Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, power-management

So, I have a home Ubuntu server, that I only use rarely, but sometimes use remotely. I would like to have it minimize the power usage, even if it requires a minute to access remotely, as I only use it a time or two per day really. How could I set my server to go into a sleep mode when not in use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use powertop (available in the repos) to see what is using the most power. It will even provide suggestions as to what can be done to improve power usage.

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
```